# Why do some STL algorithms provide an additional '_if' function instead of overloading?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stl-algorithm

Why do some STL algorithms provide an additional `'_if'` function instead of overloading it?

```
// example:
find(beg, end, val);
find_if(beg, end, pred);
```

Couldn't they just have overloaded those algorithms instead of making additional `_if` functions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those algorithms provide a named version rather than an overloaded one because both versions of the algorithm take the same number of arguments. Overloading ambiguities would therefore be possible.

To avoid any possible ambiguities, the library provides separate named versions for those algorithms, `find_if` is one of those.

Comment: "rare"? Without some SFINAE trick they would be indistinguishable by overload resolution all the time.

Answer (score 20):

It isn't clear how overload resolution would work generically. What if, say, the container contains predicates?

```
struct pred
{
  bool operator()(const pred&) const;
  friend bool operator==(const pred&,const pred&);
};

std::vector<pred> v;
pred p;
std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), p); // what should happen here?
```

This potential ambiguity is avoided by having functions with different names, each name expressing the intent more clearly.

Note that this is a simplification: there is no requirement in `std::find` that the reference object be of the same type as that `value_type` of the container, just that they be comparable for equality. The requirements for the predicate in `std::find_if` are similarly generic. Both these functions are extremely generic, which means an ambiguity could arise more easily than in the example given. For example,

```
struct foo {};

struct pred
{
  bool operator()(const foo&) const;
};

bool operator==(const foo&, const pred&);

int main()
{
  std::vector<foo> v;
  pred p;
  std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), p);    // What should this do?
  std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), p); // Here, it is clear.
}
```